# remote mysql connection error is (HY000/1130)

Tags: php, mysql, database, remote-access

I want to connect remote  mysql database with php but I get error .

Where is my mistake ? How can I solved it?
[image]

and my php code is here :

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql.somedomain.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Hopefully your mistake is not that you supply the world with your real database credentials...(though I can't imagine your password would be `12345` :D )

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  You are not allowed to connect to that database server with your current combination of username and remote host.

Comment: @Rasclatt, I I've got the same combination on my luggage :-)

Comment: Well you probably will want to change your username and password because your credentials are now in the edit of your post so anyone can get into your database even though @MikeBrant edited your post.

Answer (score 0):

The host must be authorized to connect to the server.

You need to run something like

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to u478628312_database@'88.254.234.215' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

...or better,

```
GRANT <the minimum required privileges> ON yourdatabase.* to u478628312_database@'88.254.234.215' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

followed by

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

on the server, from a user with the appropriate privileges to do so (e.g. root).

Comment: Thnks @Iserni      Where I can do them ? cmd  or cpanel ?How do I make them in cPanel

Comment: I am not familiar with cPanel. You need something server side that can talk to mysql. If you have a shell, you can use the mysql cmdline client. Or phpMyAdmin if you have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

check this way:

1. Open the localhost control panel
2. config(in apache field)
3. phpMyAdmin (config.inc.php)

you should have something like this paragraph:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

change the word 'config' with 'cookie'. then save it.
```

after that go to `C:\xampp\mysql\backup`
then copy the mysql folder and paste it in `C:\xampp\mysql\data`.

if you see error stop the apache and mysql and quit the xampp control panel, then try again.
after that start your localhost and use.